# Struts2 prepare interceptor - How to skip certain methods

Tags: java, configuration, struts2, struts2-interceptors

I have prepare interceptor in use. In one action class, I have an action method named `testSomething()`, and I also have an action method named `prepareTestSomething()`.

The problem I'm facing here is that the prepare interceptor would invoke the `prepareTestSomething()` action method as if it was a preparing method for `testSomething()`, in which case it is not.

Is there a way to make the prepare interceptor to skip the invocation for certain action methods? Like for validation interceptor, we can use "**excludeMethods**" parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prepending the `prepare` word to an `Xxx` method is the Struts2 **convention** to tell the framework that it is the `prepare()` method for the `Xxx` action method. From [the docs](https://struts.apache.org/docs/prepare-interceptor.html):

> if the action class have `prepare{MethodName}()`, it will be invoked

Instead of doing other voodoos (like excluding methods) in order to make this voodoo work, simply change the method name, it is the only right way to go.

Call it `initTestSomething()`, `initializeTestSomething()`, `preparzTestSomething()`... whatever; but please, don't use a **convention** trying to make it work for something else. It is just... wrong.